# Serving private dynamic content via CloudFront with S3 bucket static web hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Currently I want to have my SPA to be served from CloudFront along with S3 bucket hosting , meanwhile maintaining the privacy of my ECS backend server which is in private subnet with internal ALB that only listens the API calls from S3 bucket, however, I understood that it is not possible for S3 bucket to serve dynamic content from my backend since it is static, Is it possible for me to use CloudFront to serve my backend API while maintaining my ALBs to be private by setting its behaviors?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer that according to the documentation of CloudFront, every CloudFront origin must be public and since it has no access to my VPC, setting a "private ALB" as an origin is impossible.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do that. Our application in AWS was doing the same. You can add behaviors to Cloudfront

a) Add default behavior for serving static content from S3
b) Add behavior for endpoint like /api/* for serving dynamic content from private ALB

You can see a reference here

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/deliver-your-apps-dynamic-content-using-amazon-cloudfront-getting-started-template/

Comment: Requirement says to have a private ALB. "Is it possible for me to use CloudFront to serve my backend API while maintaining my ALBs to be private by setting its behaviors?"